# How to create referencing outlets for a UIScrollView inside View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode6

I'm developing my first App and now I'm stuck at something that I think it could be really simple and that's why I'm asking your help.

Today I'm working with UIScrollView for the first time and now I'm a little bit lost with the Referencing outlets inside the UIScrollView. Here are my "levels" of Storyboard:

- View

  - UIScrollView

    - View
    - UITextField
    - UITextField

Currently I need to reference some Outlets in the second View and I don't know how to reference it in my .m file because I have never done that (I just only reference outlets in the first view level) and I'm lost at the moment.

Can you help me with that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can reference to objects just the same way you do the same view, despite that you are using a scroll view with a UIView inside.

Comment: How can I do that "reference? It's something different? Can you show me an example? Beause I try to reference it and it's not working. That's why I know there is something I'm not doing right. Thanks.

Comment: Please share some of the code of your IBOutlet declarations to see what's going on. As far as I understand, you are trying to create new Outlets for the content inside the scroll view correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create new Outlets for the content inside the View inside the UIScrollView (which is inside the first View). As I showed in the main topic, for example, I would like to create new Outlet for the "UITextField". I can't show you now some code but I will in a few hours. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you continue, you should make sure you understand the basics of connecting Outlets in Xcode.

http://www.codetuition.com/ios-tutorials/connecting-iboutlets-ibactions-the-fast-way/

Hope this help. From there, just follow the same steps as you do to connect anything but now inside the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it seems pretty easy! I'm going to try with that, hope it helps. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure thing! Post back if you have any other issues :) Happy programming!